# What does capital lambda mean in this set notation?

Tags: real-analysis

This is from Abbott's Understanding Analysis textbook. (Chapter is on topology in R)

Theorem 3.2.3

(i)The union of an arbitrary collection of open sets is open.

(ii) The intersection of a finite collection of open sets is open.

I'll state part of the proof and get to my question.

Proof. To prove (i), we let $\{O_\lambda : \lambda \in \Lambda \}$ be a collection of open sets and let $O = \bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} O_\lambda$.

What does $\Lambda$ mean in this case?

Comment: It is just some index set. (I.e. any set.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\Lambda$ is an index set for the “arbitrary collection of open sets.” Perhaps an analog will help clear up why it's needed:

Suppose you want to prove a theorem about “an arbitrary collection of finitely many sets of integers.” You might start with

***Let $\mathcal S = \{S_1,S_2,\dots S_n\}$ be an arbitrary collection of $n$ sets of integers.***

To notate $\mathcal S$, you named $\mathcal S$, named the sets $S_i$, and specified $n$. You could also write $\mathcal S = \{S_i : i\in \Lambda\}$, where $\Lambda=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. The symbol $\Lambda$ is just a handy symbol to use for the indexing set for the collection.

In your case, since the arbitrary collection is not necessarily finite or countable, you can’t list the sets using integer subscripts, so using an index set is the way to go.